# Linux from scratch error v7.1 ch6.9 Glibc

Tags: linux, glibc, linux-from-scratch

So i'm trying to configure glibc2.14.1 on a lfs build (step 6.9). i get as far as configuring it when i get the following error:

```
    root:/home/glibc-build# ../glibc-2.14.1/configure --prefix=/usr --disable-profile  --enable-add-ons --enable-kernel=2.6.25 --libexecdir=/usr/lib/glibc
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 30: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 75: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 56: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 84: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 137: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 242: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 195: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 195: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 195: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 195: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 195: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 195: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: line 242: /dev/null: Permission denied
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: This script requires a shell more modern than all
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: the shells that I found on your system.
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: Please tell bug-autoconf@gnu.org and glibc about your
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: system, including any error possibly output before this
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: message. Then install a modern shell, or manually run
    ../glibc-2.14.1/configure: the script under such a shell if you do have one.
```

Any ideas on the cause of this error? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a modern shell installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error here:

http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/mail-archives/lfs-dev/2000-August/005683.html

The problem was that /dev/null belonged to a user/group which did not exist.

Answer (score -1):

whenever Permission Denied appears it means that you will have to execute the statement preceeded with sudo. Just change to root user using su -  and then write sudo followed by whatever you want to write as command.Provide root's password whenever asked.